# Using parseFloat() for decimal

Tags: javascript, parsefloat

I'm trying to make a simple calculator using buttons, but I'm having trouble when it comes to placing a decimal point.  I'm trying to take the number up to that point, add a decimal character (thus making it a string), and using `parseFloat` to make it a number once again.  Here is my code:

```
function decimalButton() {
  inputValue = inputValue + ".";
  inputValue = Number.parseFloat(inputValue);
  show(inputValue);
}
```

Where `inputValue` is originally an `int`, and `show()` simply displays whatever value I put in it.

However, when I run this code, there is no decimal added to the display, and it treats it as one large integer (for example, 44.6 is displayed and treated as 446.

But if I code out the `parseFloat` line, I'll get the correct display, but it's a string and I can't do anything with it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is not enough information here to give you an answer. We needed to see where inputValue was coming from and how it was being built. Jon Skeet wrote a very nice blog post an writing questions here http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: So you have `44.6` and append another dot in the end? What `44.6.` is supposed to mean then?

Comment: @TravisJ throbber was spinning for ~20 seconds, so I copied it to the buffer. Then I refreshed a page - there was no comment, so I pasted it once again and put some more text. Then after I submitted a new one, the former one appeared after may be 5-7 seconds. Eventual consistency is eventual.

Comment: @zerkms tthere is no dot at the end.  It displays and is treated as simply 446   That was a period from the sentence, I should've typed that better haha

Comment: @Pat so you have a number `446`, what's next? You add a dot to it so it becomes `446.` which is simply the same `446` number. What makes you thinking it should turn into `44.6`?

Comment: @zerkms 44.6 is the intended value for inputValue.  However, with this code I can only get it to display 446

Comment: So if `44.6` is the initial value for the `inputValue` and you append a dot it becomes `44.6.` which makes no sense. (that's what I already mentioned 5 minutes ago)

Comment: @zerkms I'm sorry, let me try to clarify.  I have a number, 446   I then add a dot to it, which, without the parsefloat line, displays correctly as "446." I can then add another digit to it, lets say 7, and make it "446.7".  However, I can't do anything with it, since it's a string.  With the parsefloat line, however, it displays "446", and if I try to add the dot and then a number, it ignores the dot and make it "4467".

Comment: `var v = 446; v = v + '.'; v = v + '7'; alert(parseFloat(v));` --- this alerts `446.7` as expected.

Comment: @zerkms I think you didn't understand the their problem. The OP is making a calculator, and when the user press the decimal point button, it's supposed to add a `.` to the end of it. After that, the user can add another number. But since, they're parsing to float, the program is removing the decimal point - as expected.

Comment: @Pat, you should always work only with strings, and then, when effectively calculating the user's input, you can use `eval` to parse your string and turn it into a result.

Comment: Given a string `"446."` I would expect parseFloat in any language _X_ to do one of two things: produce `446.0` or produce `446` ... I would _not_ expect it to keep the superfluous decimal character. Keep things as strings while the user is providing input, as @Buzinas says, then only turn them into numbers when the user is done. Say, the user types `446. + 3.9` you can `parseFloat("446.")` when they press the plus key - you then know you have a number followed by an operator. Or wait until they press `=` and parse the whole equation.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has a type *string* and a type *number*, but does not have separate *int* and *float* types.

You can start with some strings:

```
> var intStr   = "446";
> var floatStr = "446.0";
> var decStr   = "446.";
> var floatVal = "446.7";
```

All of these have the type *string*

```
> typeof floatStr
"string"
```

Once you parse them using the `Number` object the result is of type *number*

```
> var n = Number.parseInt(intStr);
> n
446
> typeof n
"number"
> var f = Number.parseFloat(floatVal);
> f
446.7
> typeof f
"number"
```

So both parseInt and parseFloat produce a *number*.

Parsing a string with a zero `0` fractional value drops the fractional part, because `446.0 == 446`

```
> Number.parseFloat(floatStr);
446
```

Following that, parsing a string that has a trailing decimal with no value is the same as a `.0` value. `446.0 == 446. == 446`

```
> Number.parseFloat(decStr);
446
```

If you want to keep the trailing decimal `.` you will have to maintain the variable as a *string*, and only convert it to a *number* when you are ready to perform computations with its value.

Answer (score 0):

This is because (using your example) `44.` is interpreted by Javascript as `44.0` which is the same as `44`, which is what it then converts it to.

In JS, you **do not** have multiple data types for numbers - there are no `ints`, `floats`, etc, but instead there is `number`, a data type used to represent all numbers that can be interacted with in code. The difference between `parseInt` and `parseFloat` then is that `parseInt` strips the decimal values and `parseFloat` does not, however they both still return a `number`.

If I were making a calculator as you are, I would wait until the user had entered their full number before using `parseInt` or `parseFloat` on it. Assuming that the user is inputting into some sort of text input or DOM container, **it will be a `string` anyway** in the DOM, so there is no need to convert it to a `number`. Once you do come to processing the calculations, it won't matter if `44.` is interpreted as `44`, because that is in fact what it is.

You are probably receiving `446` rather than `44.6` because the decimal is not being inserted (`parseFloat` of decimal with nothing after it removes decimal, meaning the user is actually typing `446`). Leave it as a string until the user finishes typing, then convert and the problem will be solved.